# How to reformat all files in a VS Code Project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I'm starting to work on an existing un-beautified project, and I have reformat-on-save in my IDE, so every 1-line edit turns into a whole reformatting of the file. Instead I'd like to reformat all the files in the project.

What's the easiest way to do that with VS Code?

Answer (score 6):

Try the [vscode-formatall](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ratismal.vscode-formatall) extension. It adds a `Do Format` command that reformats all files specified by the pattern in the `formatall.search.include` setting.